# Measuring sum of angles of triangles on different curvature

Tags: curvature, measurements, error-analysis

I was reading Richard Feynman’s Six Not so Easy pieces where I came across the concept of measuring geometric shapes drawn on different curved surfaces like the ones with negative and positive curvatures. So out of curiosity I drew a few triangles on a ball and using a protractor measured the sum to be approximately 210 degrees in all cases.

I wonder what would be the sum of angles of the triangle drawn on the interior of a hollow sphere. So, I took a bowl ( not an exact sphere) and drew a triangle on the inside but now I can’t measure it since the protractor won’t fit. Is there any other way to measure it? If not what would be the approximate summation? I also wonder how it would turn out on hyperboloids and more...

Comment: The sum of angles on a sphere can be up to 540 degrees (3 * 180). The interior of a sphere is also a sphere.

Comment: Kudos to you for being proactive and actually setting up an experiment. Although if you drew different triangles (say from the equator to a pole, turn by $\alpha$ degrees, go back to the equator and finally along the equator to the original point) you would see that the sum of angles is not constant. Differential geometry is the subject that investigates this sort of questions

Comment: @nwolijin yes! I tried it that way and did find the sum to be varying now. Also I think I now understand why maximum summation will be 540 degrees as from the equator the angles are 90 degrees and the angle at the pole can be taken maximum to be 360 degree so it totals up to 540 now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you draw the triangle on the outside of a thin clear glass sphere. Now assume that the lines you drew were inside instead of outside. The angles would be the same, they just may be more easily measurable on the outside of the sphere.

Comment: Woah... so it would not matter from where we are measuring it since the surface is equally curved from both sides...  right?

Comment: But this seems a little counterintuitive as I have read that negative curvatures (saddle like) will have triangles with sum of angles to be less than 180 and in case of positive curvatures to be more than 180. Maybe this will happen when the surfaces are curved to a different extent which is not in the case of glass sphere as it is uniformly curved from all sides. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes inside of the sphere has the same radius at all places

Comment: @Curiosity the shape of the saddle is different to the shape of inside of a sphere. This is a common misconception when learning about curvatures of space . The curvature of outside of sphere is not different than curvature of inside . They are the same.